# Send envelope - replacing multiple template documents

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have a question regarding the following scenario.

I have a Docusign template with 2 documents. Template contains two Template Roles with few signature tags applied on documents. There could be also Text Input tags, checkbox tags etc...

What I need is to send an envelope with documents that will replace both template documents but to apply DocuSign tags (signature, checkbox..) that were configured in the template, to apply document visibility, and as much DS template features as it can.

Signature request (envelope) is sent using DocuSign.eSign C# client library. 
I'm using following code that builds Composite Template that contains two new documents with appropriate documentIDs retrieved from DocuSign template.

```
 EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
 envDef.EmailSubject = "Subject";
 envDef.EmailBlurb = "Body";

 envDef.CompositeTemplates = new List<CompositeTemplate>();
 envDef.CompositeTemplates.Add(new CompositeTemplate
 {
      ServerTemplates = new List<ServerTemplate> {
          new ServerTemplate
          {
              Sequence = "2",
              TemplateId = "TEMPLATE_ID_GOES_HERE"
          }
      },
      InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate>
      {
           new InlineTemplate
           {
                Sequence = "1",
                Documents = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document>
                {
                    new Document
                    {
                        DocumentBase64 = "...",    //document content
                        Name ="some.pdf",             
                        DocumentId = "TEMPLATE_DOC1_ID_GOES_HERE" //ID of template document that should be replaced
                    },
                    new Document
                    {
                        DocumentBase64 = "...",  //document content
                        Name ="another.pdf",
                        DocumentId = "TEMPLATE_DOC2_ID_GOES_HERE" //ID of template document that should to be replaced
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    });
```

Envelope is successfully sent, signers can see both new documents, but there are no Tags that were configured in the Template (on Docusign Web UI), and I'd like to avoid sending recipient tabs from client.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Composite templates can definitely get tricky and complex the more in-depth you go, on the surface though I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. One thing I was never clear on was the full scope of the `sequence` param, just as a test have you tried swapping the order of the server and inline templates and making both sequence = 1?  I might try a few tests around that to help diagnose...

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequencing order so the new documents are listed first.

With composite templates, order matters. For documents, the earlier documents are used. -- So your new documents should be before the server template (and its documents).

For everything else, the later information wins.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44376770/64904

On second thought, I see that you're doing this and it is all working except that the tabs are not being applied to the new documents.

Try the `merge_roles_on_draft` query parameter. Also, if you're using anchor tabs, add the `applyAnchorTabs: 'true'` element to the `document` objects.